# How to save form to database only if its not already in the database in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Here is the code and Im wondering how can I make it so it saves if the input from the form is unique and not already in the db.

```
@login_required    
def settings(request):
    form = EmailInfoForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        form = EmailInfoForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/settings.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at form name, it seems you want unique email, so by default [`EmailField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) is not unique, you can add `unique=True` to make it unique, see [`unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) option.